# accessing segmented control selected index from another viewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm working on an app that currently has 2 view controllers.
Within the second viewcontroller, (which I'm using for settings) I use a segement control in order to determine the game's difficulty. The settings viewcontroller's purpose is to make changes to the main viewcontroller labels.
The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to bring the selected index value of the segment control from the second viewcontroller to the main one.

here's the settings screen view controller:

```
    public class SettingsScreen: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var levelPick: UISegmentedControl! // need to use this
    @IBOutlet weak var operationPick: UISegmentedControl!
    
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }   
 }
```

and the main:

```
    class MainScreen: UIViewController {
       
       @IBOutlet weak var displayText: UILabel!

       
       public override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

       }
       
       
      // how it should work:

      func setLevel() {
           switch SettingsScreen().levelPick.selectedSegmentIndex {
           // easy
           case 0:
               displaytext.text = "test1"
           // medium
           case 1:
               displaytext.text = "test2"
           // hard
           case 2:
               displaytext.text = "test3"
           default:
               break
           }

       }

       @IBAction func Roll(_ sender: UIButton) {
           setLevel()
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Check this: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: How about updating the changes into a UserDefault variable and accessing that.

Comment: @myjunk How exactly? The whole point of my post is that I can’t find a proper way to access variables from the second viewcontroller

Comment: It actually depends on how your arch your app, there's lots of ways to pass variables to 2nd VC, some are more complicated than most, and some are simple. From your code example, maybe something simple can be used, I've posted an example answer which you can utilise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Delegate pattern or the Closure Callback pattern.
like this:

** SettingsScreen:**

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    var segmentIndex: Int = 0
    
    var closure: ((_ segmentIndex: Int) -> ())?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var levelPick: UISegmentedControl!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.levelPick.selectedSegmentIndex = self.segmentIndex

    }
    
    @IBAction func levelPickAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        guard let closure = self.closure else {
            return
        }
        closure(levelPick.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
    
}
```

** MainScreen:**

```
    class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var segmentIndex: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var displayText: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    @IBAction func Roll(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let vc = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController)
        vc.segmentIndex = segmentIndex
        vc.closure = { [weak self] segmentIndex in
            self!.segmentIndex = segmentIndex
            switch segmentIndex {
            // easy
            case 0:
                self!.displayText.text = "test1"
            // medium
            case 1:
                self!.displayText.text = "test2"
            // hard
            case 2:
                self!.displayText.text = "test3"
            default:
               break
            }
        }
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: hey. well it doesn't crash anymore, but also doesn't change anything, like the code is just not there. Also, the selected index from the settingscreen resets everytime i switch to the main screen

Comment: @Roei you are right. I added a segmentIndex variable in both ViewController. check it out.

Comment: Still doesn’t work, nothing has changed. Btw I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Roei Check out this project: 
https://github.com/AhmadYasserAlshalabi/ClosureCallback

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach. Instead of trying to figure out the selected index in your main controller, you could directly update the labels of the main controller from the settings controller. You can use NSNotification to achieve this.

In your main controller viewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("notification1"), object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
    self.myFunction // basically update labels and call your self.present() here
}
```

In settings controller in your UISegmentedControl's value changed event:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mySegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(function), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func function() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("notification1"), object: nil)
}
```

Comment: I want to update the labels with the Roll button inside the main viewcontroller. How can I achieve that? Also what do you mean by self.present() ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're referring to a referencing a user specified `SegmentedIndex` based on some setting changes, you could utilise `UserDefaults` to store that index for later retrieval. This would be Simpler but it also depends on what you're actually after.

```
public class SettingsScreen: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var levelPick: UISegmentedControl! // need to use this
@IBOutlet weak var operationPick: UISegmentedControl!

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}   


  @IBAction func levelPickPressed(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch levelPick.selectedSegmentIndex {
      case 0:        // Easy
        defaults.set(0, forKey: "levelPick_Level")
        
      case 1:        // Med
        defaults.set(1, forKey: "levelPick_Level")
        
      case 2:       // Hard
        defaults.set(2, forKey: "levelPick_Level")

      default:
        break
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your MainScreen code

```
  func setLevel() {
       levelPick = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "levelPick_Level")
       switch levelPick {
       // easy
       case 0:
           displaytext.text = "test1"
       // medium
       case 1:
           displaytext.text = "test2"
       // hard
       case 2:
           displaytext.text = "test3"
       default:
           break
       }
   }
```

Comment: what did you mean by this line - defaults.set(0, forKey: "levelPick_Level")? I have changed it to levelPick.setValue(0, forKey: "levelPick_Level") and it works but crashes as soon as I select a different index

Comment: why did you not use ```defaults.set(0, forKey: "levelPick_Level")``` is it not working? This is setting up ```userDefaults``` to store your user selected ```selectedSegmentIndex``` I hope you googled it at least (https://learnappmaking.com/userdefaults-swift-setting-getting-data-how-to/)

btw - ```setValue(_:forKey)``` is meant for a key:value dictionary (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415969-setvalue)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for trying to help. I finally managed to get it right. In the end I used Segues to pass the variables from one viewcontroller to another.